# Node.js get pid of a spawned process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experimenting with node.js. Trying to spawn processes but cannot seem to get the right PID back on close. If i run the function below it will spawn a process but the returning ls.pid in the on close function will always be the pid from the last process.

```
function app_cmd(cmd, args,path) {
  ls = spawn ( cmd , args , { cwd : path } );
  console.log ( cmd +' ' + ls.pid );
  ls.on ( 'close' , function(code) {
    console.log ( 'returning: ' + code + ' on ' + ls.pid );
  } );
  return ls.pid;
}
```

So if i call the function twice i get the following output (note the two times 6940 in the return):

```
php.exe 6076
php.exe 6940
returning: 0 on 6940
returning: 0 on 6940
```

Anyone has a pointer for me on how to get the proper PID back in the onClose?

Much appreciated,

Ties

Comment: Well written question with a rep of 1. Thanks!

Comment: this is just another flavor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example where instead of a loop doing the work, you're calling the function twice. Ensuring that the variable being used isn't shared between calls resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're declarling `ls` as a global by mistake causing it to be overwritten the second time, adding a `var|let|const` should fix it.

```
function app_cmd(cmd, args,path) {
  const ls = spawn ( cmd , args , { cwd : path } );
  console.log ( cmd +' ' + ls.pid );
  ls.on ( 'close' , function(code) {
    console.log ( 'returning: ' + code + ' on ' + ls.pid );
  } );
  return ls.pid;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution.. works as a train. I looked my butt of for a global declaration but could not find it in the code. ls is quite common variable declaration so maybe somewhere in the sub libs. Making the object a constance solved everything.